# Upgrading from XP

Tags: system-installation, system

I have an old XP laptop running a 600m processor.  I downloaded Ubuntu. I have not run install yet.  What is the next step?

Comment: Without mentioning which type of Ubuntu installer you downloaded (DVD or USB image, or Windows installer) and which specific part you're having trouble with, this question is too broad.

Answer (score 0):

In general, I guess the next step is to decide whether you want to fully replace your current OS or run them side-by-side.

Have you tried reading the installation instructions on the Ubuntu site?  If so, which specific part are you having trouble with?

http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/install-desktop-latest